# Tootip in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, tooltip

I have a `GridView` with a hyperlink listed below. The tooltip displays the correct "case_nbr" value for each row.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
 NavigateUrl='<%# "~/WSCaseProcess.aspx?CaseVerNum=" + Item.case_nbr %>' 
 ToolTip= '<%# Item.case_nbr %>'><%# Item.case_nbr %></asp:HyperLink>
```

I would like to prefix the "case_nbr" value with the text "Case Number" e.g. the tooltip should show "**Case Number: case number value**". I would need a solution in the `aspx` markup and not in the code behind in "row_data_bound"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format` function to achieve your result of concatenation.

An example is below:

```
ToolTip = '<%# (String.Format("Case Number: {0}", Eval("case_nbr"))) %>'
```